# How to change one attribute display in yii2 DetailView widget?

Tags: yii2, detailview

I am using `yii\widgets\DetailView` to display some single object informations like this:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'id',
        'username',
        'email:email',
        [
            'attribute'=>'status',
            'value' => $model->status,
        ],
        'created_at:date',
        'updated_at:date',
    ],
]) ?>
```

I want to display status in different color. So basically I would like to either add class of `.red` to the wrapping `<td>` tag, or even better to wrap the status with `<span class="red">{value}</span>`

`GridView` has `contentOptions` which is really easy to use. But with `DetailView` I have tried with `options` and `template`, but I couldn't make it work. Maybe I did something wrong, or I need to use some other attribute.

So this is not working for me:

```
[
    'attribute'=>'status',
    'value' => $model->status,
    'template' => '<tr><th>{label}</th><td><span class="red">{value}</span></td></tr>'
],
```

Can someone explain how to achieve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply try :

```
[
    'attribute'=>'status',
    'value' => '<span class="red">'.$model->status.'</span>',
    'format' => 'raw',
],
```

[Read more](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-detailview.html#$attributes-detail).